# .NET ListView in List Mode stop display in coloumns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm using a System.Windows.Forms.ListView control in my application with its View property set to "List". However, the content ends up being in coloumns instead of a single coloumn (ie. There are only horizontal scrollbars instead of vertical ones). Is there any way to display the data in a single coloumn?[image: A screenshot of the ListView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you are only displaying text, use the ListView in Detail mode and set the header style to None to remove the column headers. You will also need to ensure your single column fills the box.

Of course unless you need ListView's features you might be able to just use a ListBox instead.

Comment: Great! I just used a ListBox with no problems!